# reCaptcha inserting div at the end of the body tag

Tags: html, recaptcha

I'm having a bit of an issue here. I currently have Google reCaptcha inside of a form that is inside of a pop up box, and whenever the image verification box is opened, it inserts this div in the bottom of the DOM, at the very end of the body tag. It's positioned absolutely, however it's causing my footer to jump up and stay there even after the box is closed, until the page is refreshed, like when the form is submitted. I can't seem to figure out how to change this, I think that even moving the div would help, since it's being placed underneath my footer right now. Thoughts? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to try and remove the element, here is the code to do it.

```js
(function(){
  'use strict';
  var inserted = document.getElementById('inserted-by-goo');
  inserted.parentElement.removeChild(inserted);
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>reCaptcha inserting div at the end of the body tag</title>
</head>
<body>

  <form>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
  
  <div id="inserted-by-goo">reCaptcha inserting div at the end of the body tag</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not a defining class or even attribute to target this div with. Also, I would like to move the div, not remove it entirely. Thank you though.

Comment: Maybe provide some html and js for us to look at further.